# Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 No Option to Create "Windows 8 Store App"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-8

I am trying to create sample application for `Windows 8 Embedded Handheld` or `Windows Store App`, for that I have following configuration.

**Configuration:**
 1. Windows 8 64Bit OS
 2. Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition With Update 4 Installed
 3. Windows Phone 8 SDK, Downloaded From [This](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471) Link.
 4. Windows 8 Embedded Handheld SDK, Downloaded From [This](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=41541) Link.

But when I start my Visual Studio I don't see any option for Creating Windows Store App as Given in [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTbfZpc3R2s) video.

Also I am not able to see installed Windows 8 Phone SDK and W8EH SDK in, about screen of the Visual Studio 2012.

**UPDATE**
It will be very helpful if we have list of all the supported versions of Visual Studio with there targeted use, like for Desktop/Mobile(or 'Phone' it is also one more confusion)/Handheld/Embedded/Store, else it is very confusing for the beginners to decide which version of Visual Studio to use for development of Embedded/Handheld Application development.

Comment: What project templates do you see?

Comment: I see "Windows Forms Application", "WPF Applications", "Console Application", "Class Library" and "Empty Project" options under Visual C#.

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong edition of VS Express.  You have the edition for Windows Desktop, which is for creating traditional Windows desktop applications.  You need the edition for Windows, which is for creating Store apps that target the Modern UI.

Comment: Can you point me to the location/version/name of the edition that i have to install for developing the Store app, as mentioned on the windows phone 8 SDK site it is Visual Studio 2012 Update 4 RC 4 or greater, which i have.

Comment: This is the edition you need: http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30664. I don't know what Update that includes but you can install that afterwards easily enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, So i need "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" and then i need to install all the SDK for Windows 8 Phone and Windows 9 Embedded Handheld. I will get it and check. thanks again.

Comment: Also one more thing, what is the diff. between "VS2012 Express For Windows-8" and "VS2012 Express For Windows Phone 8". First one is for Windows-8 desktop apps and 2nd one for Windows-8 Phone app, is it that? or both are same, it will be helpful if we have list of all the supported versions with there targeted use. else it is very confusing for the beginners.

Comment: "VS2012 Express for Windows 8" is for Windows 8 native applications (not desktop ones, Modern UI ones). "VS2012 Express for Windows Phone 8" is for writing apps for Windows Phone 8, not for Windows 8 on a tablet or PC. The names are fairly straightforward, if you remember that VS Express is designed to have one edition for each type of project (web, desktop, phone etc.) rather than the paid-for VS which does it all in the same application.

Comment: I installed "Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8" but when i try to open the sample application with ".csproj" extension then i get error as Unsupported. so i think it is not working.

Comment: Perhaps you need the one for Windows Phone then.  I had actually forgotten that there were separate editions for Windows Store apps and Windows Phone Store apps in 2012.  They are combined in 2013 I believe but I don't actually use Express editions at all, so I'm not up with all the details.